# JavaScript equivalent of PHP's chr() function

Tags: javascript, php, character-encoding

How to transform the following code from PHP to JavaScript?

```
$str = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++) {
    $str .= chr($i);
}
```

I know `String.fromCharCode(n)` in JavaScript is similar to `chr(n)` in PHP, but it seems they return different characters when n is greater than 127.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: You need to include your inputs and outputs, as well as any errors you've run into.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? JavaScript doesn't use ASCII at all and your strings probably don't do it either (we are in 2016!).

Comment: Why is this question on hold? OP asks for a js implementation of a given PHP reference code. You can't be more precise than that.

Answer (score 7):

PHP's chr() function interprets input from 0..127 as ascii values and input from 128..255 as IBM code page 437 (CP437, proprietary extended ascii) values. This is the complete ASCII table used by PHP: http://www.asciitable.com/

JavaScript's String.fromCharCode(i) method interprets input as UTF-8 values, which are similar to ascii (from 0..127) but not the IBM CP437 extended ascii (from 128..255).

You can try to recreate PHP's chr() function in JavaScript, e. g. as follows (untested):

```
function chr(n) {
    if (n < 128) {
        return String.fromCharCode(n);
    } else {
        return "ÇüéâäàåçêëèïîìÄÅÉæÆôöòûùÿÖÜ¢£¥₧ƒáíóúñÑªº¿⌐¬½¼¡«»░▒▓│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╝╜╛┐└┴┬├─┼╞╟╚╔╩╦╠═╬╧╨╤╥╙╘╒╓╫╪┘┌█▄▌▐▀αßΓπΣσµτΦΘΩδ∞φε∩≡±≥≤⌠⌡÷≈°∙·√ⁿ²■ "[n - 128];
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use this function when arg is negative. eg. chr(-77) returns � in PHP. How to do it in javascript?